# How to set FirstName and LastName value in AcitveDirectory using UserPrincipal

Tags: c#, active-directory, identity

The UserPrincipal class in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement does not contain any property to set the First and Last name, it has GivenName, Surname, DisplayName and Name but which property is used to set the FirstName and Last name from UserPrincipal.

Comment: Surname is Last Name, and GivenName is First Name.

Comment: ok, Thanks!, I was using DisplayName and Name properties.

Comment: Check out [Richard Mueller's site](http://www.rlmueller.net/UserAttributes.htm) which has some excellent AD reference Excel sheets, listing all the attributes and how they e.g. map to the "AD Users & Computers" Utility

Comment: @marc_s: good information on Active Directory, something to refer whenever necessary, Thanks,